# Proving a statement about a right invertible matrix

Tags: matrices, proof-writing

I'm a bit confused on conducting the following proof:

> A $\in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ is right invertible implies for every right inverse $A_R^{-1}$ of $A$, $A_R^{-1}A$ is idempotent.

How do you prove such a statement like the one above?

Answer (score 1):

Idempotency of a matrix means $A \cdot A = A$

In our case

$A_R^{-1}A \cdot A_R^{-1}A= A_R^{-1}A$

$\Leftrightarrow A_R^{-1}(A \cdot A_R^{-1})A= A_R^{-1}A$

$\Leftrightarrow A_R^{-1}A= A_R^{-1}A$

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*: Write out the definition of idempotent for $A_R^{-1}A$ and check if you can find en expression on the left that can be removed because it equals the identity.